# Clojure using ref and alter for multi-thread states

Tags: clojure

I am trying to do something trivial, calculate something using agents, if the final agent value is smaller than some ref variable, update ref variable.

I having trouble finding a way to update the ref variable to "swap".

```
(def shortest (ref [1 2 3 4 5])
(def var1 (ref [[1 2 3]]))
(def transfer [avar]
    (dosync
         (if (< (count var1) (count shortest)
             (alter shortest @avar); or whatever is appropriate!
         )
    )

)
```

I thought swap! would work but that's for atom only.  (and i'm not sure it would work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ref-set](http://clojure.org/refs) is useful if you just want to put a value in a ref.

```
user> (def shortest (ref [1 2 3 4 5]))
#'user/shortest
user> (def var1 (ref [1 2 3]))
#'user/var1
```

functions need `defn` instead of `def`:

```
user> (defn transfer [avar]
        (dosync
         (if (< (count @avar) (count @shortest)) ;; use @ to use the value in the ref
           (ref-set shortest @avar)))) ;; did you intend to use avar here?
#'user/transfer
```

and now to test it:

```
user> @shortest
[1 2 3 4 5]
user> (transfer var1)
[1 2 3]
user> @shortest
[1 2 3]
```